# Blogger Minimum Requirements

Tags: blogger

If you wipe out blank your blogger's html theme, what is the absolute minimum you need to get a page running?
Say, give us the entire code for a page with only a paragraph saying "What's up?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sample HTML with only a paragraph in Blogger.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir='ltr' lang='en' xml:lang='en' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
  <head>
<title>Title can be changed  by editing only</title>
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
</body>

<b:skin><![CDATA[]]></b:skin>
<b:section id='main'/>
</html>
```

1. Notice that the title is no longer dynamic. It can be made dynamic. That works as well.
2. Same as point 1. The `html dir` too can be made dynamic. Here I made it static.
3. No `post page` will open. It will display only this page. Try creating one and open its URL. :)
4. The trick lies in this part

```
<b:skin><![CDATA[]]></b:skin>
<b:section id='main'/>
```

Add those two lines outside the `body` and add any HTML you want.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry my upvotes don't count yet. Any place you'd recommend to learn the base of blogger's html?

Comment: Coincidentally I started today as well ;) . The blogger official documentation seems to be a good place to start if you are good in `HTML` , `CSS` and `JavaScript`. Otherwise all these can go together. I am glad my answer helped you. Good luck. :)